# Coremltools: XGBoost JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, ios, xgboost, coreml, coremltools

I created a model using XGBoost library and I want to convert it to Core ML model with [coremltools](https://github.com/apple/coremltools). I saved model like this:

`xgb.save(xgb1, 'xgb.model')`

My python file looks like:

`import coremltools 
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.xgboost.convert('../xgb.model') 
coremltools.save('my_model.mlmodel')`

Unfortunately, there is an error:

`[...] File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

I wonder what causes the error. 
Model works well in R, exporting looks fine too. Maybe someone has converted xgboost model and can help me, thanks!